# Change View Controller on UITableViewCell Tap

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

I'm trying to change the View Controller when someone Taps on a Table View Cell. However Im not doing it the conventional way. I am submethoding the method that actually detects the tap so I could use it from any other class. Here is how I am doing it:

**TableSource.cs**

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            if (OnRowSelected != null) {
                OnRowSelected (this, new RowSelectedEventArgs (tableView, indexPath));
            }
        }

public class RowSelectedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public UITableView tableView { get; set; }
            public NSIndexPath indexPath { get; set; }

public RowSelectedEventArgs(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) : base()
            { 
                this.tableView = tableView;
                this.indexPath = indexPath;
            }
        }

public event EventHandler<RowSelectedEventArgs> OnRowSelected;
```

**Request.cs**

```
tableSourceTable.OnRowSelected += (object sender, TableSource<Datum>.RowSelectedEventArgs e) => {

 vc = new InstagramModalController (){instaData = tableSourceTable.instaData[e.indexPath.Row]};
                         this.navControl.PushViewController(this.vc,true);

                        this.getMediaID(tableSourceTable.instaData[e.indexPath.Row].link);

                        new UIAlertView(tableSourceTable.instaData[e.indexPath.Row].user.full_name.ToString(), 
                            tableSourceTable.instaData[e.indexPath.Row].caption.text.ToString(), null, "OK", null).Show();
                        e.tableView.DeselectRow (e.indexPath, true);
                    };
```

That is all the code from the TableSource class and I would be okay with any change.

Comment: What is/isn't working?  Does your event handler get called?

Comment: Well the actual TableView isnt in the request class, its in another class called `StreamView.cs` and I call the method from this class on the StreamView Class, so i think that is where the problem roots from

Comment: That doesn't answer either of my questions.

Comment: Sorry @Jason What doesnt work is that it doesnt push the view controller to the `InstagramModalController` it says that object reference is not an instance of the object

Comment: Then either vc or navControl is null.  Which one is it?

Comment: I believe its vc @Jason

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to do this?